# IntelliJ IDEA cannot debug after Browserstack SDK integration to selenium test framework using Cucumber Serenity (maven build)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, debugging, browserstack

I'm facing an issue with debugging after integrate my current selenium test framework with Browserstack.
Before integration, it stops at break point in java code to debug. However, even I run the same test scenario and same checkpoint,
**browserstack.yml file:**

```
userName: MYUSERNAME
accessKey: MYACCESSKEY
projectName: MY PROJECT
buildName: THE BUILD
buildIdentifier: '#${BUILD_NUMBER}' # Supports strings along with either/both ${expression}
framework: cucumber
platforms:
  - deviceName: Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra
    browserName: chrome # Try 'samsung' for Samsung browser
    osVersion: 12.0
parallelsPerPlatform: 1
source: cucumber:intellij:v1.1.2
browserstackLocal: true # <boolean> (Default false)
debug: true # <boolean> # Set to true if you need screenshots for every selenium command ran
networkLogs: true # <boolean> Set to true to enable HAR logs capturing
consoleLogs: errors # <string> Remote browser's console debug levels to be printed (Default: errors)
interactiveDebugging: true
seleniumLogs: true
```

**Sample in feature file:**

```
  @tag
  Scenario: As a customer, I want to verify ABC
    Given User go to page "<URL>"
    When User input phone number
    And User click on button submit
    Then User should see "XYZ"
```

**POM.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>vn.auto</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <auto.version>4.0.29</auto.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.0.70</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.version>2.0.70</serenity.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <sonar.sources>pom.xml,src/main/java,features</sonar.sources>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.auto</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-core</artifactId>
            <version>${auto.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-serenity</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-web</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-mobile</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-sql</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-report</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vn.hoselato</groupId>
            <artifactId>hoselato-tool-integration</artifactId>
            <version>${hoselato.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber4</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-emailer</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>browserstack-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${com.browserstack:browserstack-java-sdk:jar}"</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${com.browserstack:browserstack-java-sdk:jar}"
-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                    <!--<parallel>methods</parallel>-->
                    <!--<threadCount>4</threadCount>-->
                    <!--<perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tags>${tags}</tags>
                    <reports>email</reports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-emailer</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>getClasspathFilenames</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>properties</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>object_repositories/**</include>
                    <include>config/**</include>
                    <include>data/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

•   **Maven command line**: clean verify serenity:aggregate -Dmaven.surefire.debug -DforkCount=1 "-Dcucumber.options=--tags  @tag

**Actual Result:**
When I click on button Debug of IntelliJ, a new build displays on Browserstack Dashboard, I click on "Interactive Debugging", then test steps start and end. It doesn't stop in my Java code to debug.
Do you have any experience about this?
I've asked support from Browserstack but the issue is still there.
Please help me to give your idea/suggestion. Thanks a lot!

I've tried to increase -DforkCount=0 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share with us any error/exception message received during test execution?

Comment: Yes sure. Please help to have a look

[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.372.7-hotspot\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\myaccount\.m2\repository\com\browserstack\browserstack-java-sdk\1.8.6\browserstack-java-sdk-1.8.6.jar -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar

Comment: C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire8824677851888095320\surefirebooter7152078299922823454.jar C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire8824677851888095320 2023-07-22T22-19-55_265-jvmRun1 surefire4886343855642447611tmp surefire_0854870395964311220tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

Comment: [ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.372.7-hotspot\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\myaccount\.m2\repository\com\browserstack\browserstack-java-sdk\1.8.6\browserstack-java-sdk-1.8.6.jar -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire8824677851888095320\surefirebooter7152078299922823454.jar C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire8824677851888095320 2023-07-22T22-19-55_265-jvmRun1 surefire4886343855642447611tmp surefire_0854870395964311220tmp"

Comment: [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:748)
[ERROR]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)

Answer (score 0):

This looks more specific to BrowserStack SDK you are using, I would kindly suggest you to please reach out to BrowserStack support team for further help on this.

Comment: yes. I already raised question to them but it is still not resolved